# PCI RAID Controller Card bandwith for a RAID1 array of SATA III drives

Tags: raid, hardware-raid

I want to build a hardware RAID1 setup with two  HDDs (SATA3, 7200, 64MB cache) and I'm looking at two, almost the same, Adaptec cards (6405E vs 6805E)

The 6405E is PCI-E 2.0 x1 while the 6805E is PCI-E 2.0 x4. Both are 128MB cache.

If I take the 6405E, will the PCI x1 bandwidth bottleneck be really visible? This won't be a system drive, just data.

NB: Other Adaptec models might better suit my needs/budget (eg: 6405), but I can't find them online.

PS: Yes I know, the battery module is not included (6405E) / not possible (6805E)

Answer (score 1):

If either will work, and you're only connecting 7200RPM SATA drives to it, I doubt you'll saturate a PCIe 2.0 1x lane.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express

States that it should be able to perform at about 500mb/s, per lane (the 4x connector would offer about 2gb/s). PCI Express 2.0 has about a 20% overhead, so your actual maximum throuput is about 400 mb/s, but throughput of 7200 RPM drives is generally under the 100 mb/s range.  Unless you need more than 4 disks, I think the 6405E will fit nicely.

Comment: As far as the battery module goes, My opinion is that you shouldn't need it unless you have mission critical production data that has a lot of random IOPS.  Considering you're using SATA 3 7200 RPM drives instead of 10k ones, I think you can get away with putting the computer on a decent UPS.

Comment: For some dumb reason, I forgot to take in account the throughput of a HDD drive... well below 600MB/s.